# Mid Range Server Motherboard Recommendation (linux)

Tags: linux, hardware, ecc

I am looking for a mid price range motherboard for a Linux Server.
It should have support for ECC memory.

On all other aspects I am pretty open minded!

Any suggestions or recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People don't really build server-class systems from individual components these days. If this is something for production use, definitely try to go with a pre-built vendor-supported solution like Dell or HP.

If you need more customizability, you can look into [Supermicro's offerings](http://www.supermicro.com/index.cfm) as well.